# find directory where my extended class is with php

Tags: php

lets say we have a dir

script.php is a class that is extending a controller class from index.php,

```
application/helloworld/script.php
index.php
```

is there a way to return the folder `helloworld` from index.php ( controller )  ?

edit*

script.php

```
class Helloworld extends Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        echo 'helloworld';  
    }
}
```

index.php

```
class Controller
{
    function wherethescript(){
        # trying to find folder where helloworld.php is in from this class
    }
}

include_once 'application/helloworld/helloworld.php';
$x=new Helloworld;
$x->wherethescript();
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? How would index.php get near that folder to begin with and how does script.php play into this?

Comment: edited sorry for the lack of information

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have *any* path, [`basename`](http://www.php.net/basename) will get you the last part of it. [`dirname`](http://www.php.net/dirname) chops off the last part. The `__FILE__` constant contains the path of the current file. So something like `basename(dirname(__FILE__))` in `script.php` should do.

That can be shortened to `basename(__DIR__)` in PHP 5.3 and up.

If you want to do this from `index.php` and not `script.php`, you can [reflect](http://www.php.net/ReflectionClass) on the object to get where it was defined:

```
$helloReflection = new ReflectionClass($this);
echo $helloReflection->getFilename();
```

Answer (score -2):

[dirname()](http://php.net/dirname) and [explode()](http://php.net/explode) will do that for you.

With dirname() you will get the full path, with the line below only the current dir; [getcwd()](http://php.net/getcwd) will also help.

```
explode( '/', dirname( __FILE__ ), 1 )
```

Comment: Nope.  You missed the point of the question.  `__FILE__` gets the filename of the parent-class, not the child class.

Comment: `getcwd()` will get where the file is executed from (current working directory), not where the instantiated object file resides. EG:  `/home/user/index.php` -> `include /home/user/lib/file.php` if file.php has `echo getcwd();` it will output `/home/user` instead of `/home/user/lib`